# how to unobserve after image is loaded?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, lazy-loading

I am doing `lazy-load` of my image . when it come to `view port` I am loading my image.it is working fine .I am able to load image when it comes to view port.But I am facing one issue.

when I loose view port my image is `gone` and come back it fetch again.so I need to `unobserve` my listner.

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-lovelace-yjfl9?file=/src/App.js

```
const Card = ({ src }) => {
  const target = useRef();
  const root = useRef();
  const [isThingIntersecting, setThingIntersecting] = useState(false);
  console.log("isThingIntersecting", isThingIntersecting);
  useIntersectionObserver({
    root,
    target,
    rootMargin: "0px",
    threshold: 0.02,
    // What do we do when it intersects?
    // The signature of this callback is (collectionOfIntersections, observerElement).
    onIntersect: ([{ isIntersecting }]) => setThingIntersecting(isIntersecting)
  });

  return (
    <img className={"img"} ref={target} src={isThingIntersecting ? src : ""} />
  );
};
```

In this line problem is happening `src={isThingIntersecting ? src : ""}` when it true it fetch the image .but when it goes out of view port it remove image and when it come again it fetch again.

can we `unobserve` the target when it fetch the image .I don't want to fetch again and again.

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-lovelace-yjfl9?file=/src/App.js:732-1349

Comment: what is your use case here? You want to show the image when in the viewport and then it should stay after that. Correct?

Comment: yes correct..that is the use case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea for lazy loading images using `Intersection Observer` is to fetch an image only when it reaches in the viewport. Hence, you would be able to save on bytes and initial page load would be smoother.

To analyse the viewport `Intersection Observer` API could be used.

Here the mistake you are doing it to remove the image `src` when the user moves away from the image. To avoid that you can set the image src once when intersect is true for the image. You can use the `onIntersect` to add that logic.

Made a few tweaks to your code [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/green-cookies-su1rc?file=/src/App.js)

**Improvement:**

- Remove the observer right after the image source is set.

After the image had been loaded you don't need to observe on the image anymore. You can remove the event listener after setting the image `src` attribute.